# Hide Option within Select box using Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm looking to hide just one option within a select box using Jquery/Javascript. I've tried CSS to display: none but it doesn't work on all browsers and I can't edit the option directly to add "hidden" or similar.

https://impactdigitaldev.co.uk/bookly/

In the first drop-down "category" I'm trying to hide the "lane hire" option. Which you can see has a value="5" so I've tried the following script but it's not working if you have any suggestions I'd be really grateful.

```
$("#cats option[value='5']").remove();
```

I also tried without the ID and still no luck

```
$("option[value='5']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape the block quote:

```js
document.querySelector("option[value='5']").remove();
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
<select>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's still not removing it, even though I can see the code works correctly. Is it perhaps firing the javascript before the bookly booking form has loaded?

Comment: @MattCooper it is quite possible. You need to run `remove` when the options were already defined. If my snippet works in all your browsers, then this is a workable proof-of-concept, so, if you apply this to your problem and it does not work, then it is probably an algorithmic problem, as you already suspected.

Comment: If you need further help with your problem, then you will need to provide more details to your question, as from my position it is impossible to guess why your options did not exist when you tried to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("select option[value='5']").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="0">Category</option>
   <option value="1">coaching</option>
   <option value="5">lane hire</option>
</select>
```

Working fiddle
https://codepen.io/hermes14/pen/VwyrXjr?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cats option[value='5']").remove();
```

Does work, you've got an uncaught type error in your console though which probably is why the script doesn't run.

As you can see in the screenshot below I ran your snippet in the browser console, resulting in a removed option.

[image]

In case you are interested, this can be easily handled through regular javascript as such:

```js
document.querySelector("#cats option[value='5']").remove();
```

```html
<div class="bookly-form-group" id="cats" data-type="category">
<label>Category</label> 
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="0">Category</option>
      <option value="1">coaching</option>
      <option value="5">lane hire</option>
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>
```